# How to configure to print out Ignite logs

Tags: log4j, ignite

I want to see the INFO level logs that Ignite prints during its running(so that it will help me on what Ignite is doing). I am using the following log4j.properties to make Ignite print INFO level logs,but the logs are not printed out. 
Are there special configuration to make Ignite logs printed out?
Thanks.

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, stdout , R
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %d - [TS] %c %M(%L) - %m%n
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=c:/ioc.ignite.log
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %d - [TS] %c %M(%L) - %m%n

log4j.logger.org.apache.ignite=INFO
log4j.logger.org.springframework=WARN
```

Answer (score 1):

Please follow below steps:

e.g. if you are using log4j for logging

1. configure ignite/config/ignite-log4j.xml in gridLogger of IgniteConfiguration

   e.g.

   .........
2. uncomment "CONSOLE" appender in ignite/config/ignite-log4j.xml
3. copy ignite/libs/optional/ignite-log4j/log4j.jar and ignite/libs/optional/ignite-log4j/ignite-log4j.jar in ignite/libs/ folder
4. you can also set IGNITE_LOG_HOME environment variable to redirect the logs to any file

Comment: setting gridLogger property resets any log4j2 configurations that you had set before using it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `<CLASSPATH>/config/ignite-log4j.xml` file instead of `log4j.properties`.

Comment: Thanks @a_gura, I am sorry that when i copied the ignite-log4j.xml from Ignite binary relase into my project(Resources/config/ignite-log4j.xml) and made its log directory and file.. When i run the Ignite.start() in my IDE java class, no log file(specified in the ignite-log4j.xml)specify in the  is created.

Comment: Do you have `ignite-log4j` dependency in your project?

Comment: Thanks @a_gura. Yes, I have had the `ignite-log4j` dependency ..but there is no log printed out...I will spend more time investigating this.